# Passing dynamic parameters to ASP MVC using Jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to pass dynamic parameters from jquery to mvc controller. This is my jquery function

```
function OpenBrowserUrl(type, params)
{
    window.open("{0}?linkType={1}&{2}".format(URL.openBrowserLinkURL, type, $.param(params)), '_blank');
}
```

params would be different things based on who passes it in. For example, it's an object like this: `var param = { P1: "Test1", P2: "Test2" }`

I am trying to bind those in MVC Controller. This is what it looks like right now:

```
    public virtual RedirectResult OpenBrowserLink(object urlParameters)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> paramsPair = new RouteValueDictionary(urlParameters);
        foreach (var item in paramsPair)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item.Key);
        }
    }
```

However, it's not binding properly. the values are empty. On fiddler, this is how it's sending data: http://www.url.com?param1=1&param2=2&param3=3

Any idea what's going on? or Is there a better way to handle this? Basically I am trying to mimic the way Html Helpers send parameters and bind it from the controller side using JQuery. HtmlHelper example: `Html.TextboxFor(m => m.Text, new { Param1=1, Param2=2, Param3=3 });`

Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 0):

Model binder won't work because your `object urlParameters` has no properties. You should either create strongly typed model:

```
public class UrlParamerters
{
    public string Param1 {get; set;}
    public string Param2 {get; set;}
    public string Param3 {get; set;}
}
```

or change your action signature:

```
public virtual RedirectResult OpenBrowserLink(string[] params)
```

and just pass an array or parameters.